# Adding data-order attribute value in <td> tag for custom sorting does not recognize order attribute

Tags: angular, datatables, angular11

I am trying to apply custom sorting on a **column (Issues-Ids)**. I have looked different approaches of custom sorting on a specific column but could not find any proper solution.
Lastly I tried to follow order-data approach [data-order](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html), but when I tried to provide value to data-order attribute using:
`<td data-order="dataOrderValue({{row.id}})">`

It gives me following error:

`G0303: Can't bind to 'order' since it isn't a known property of 'td'.`

BTW, Hardcoded value (e.g. order-data="SO-123") works fine, but it gives same value to column values.

Comment: I think you should try property binding, smth like... 
`[data-order]="dataOrderValue({{row.id}})"`

Comment: Tried that, Getting same error again. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Try using `.sort()` method, and define your own sorting logic to sort the table rows as desired...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @Nader I have been using jquery datable and I am not sure this is the right way to overwrite sort function provided by jquery data-table itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is attribute biding, not property binding. Try it with the **attr**, like:

```
[attr.data-order]="dataOrderValue({{row.id}})"
```

For reference:

[attribute-binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding)

Comment: Works now. Have been using [attr.some-attribute] for a while but did not had understating of it. 
Thanks